# Storing parameter templates to create new entities from?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, templates, entity

My entity system for my game uses templates to lay out how entities are created.  Something like:

```
EntityTemplateManager.register("zombie",
    new PhysicsComponent(10), // speed
    new SpriteComponent("zombie"), // graphic
    new HealthComponent(100) // health
);
```

I like this part of the system because it makes sure I don't miss any parameters or screw up their type.

Then I can create a new entity like this:

`entity : Entity = EntityTemplateManager.create("zombie");`

Pretty straight forward.

What I do now, to actually create the entity, is have the EntityTemplateManager create 1 entity to use as a default, then I call clone() on the entity and it goes through and clone()s all of its components and returns the result.

Actual code:

```
public function clone() : Entity
{
    var components : Vector.<Component> = new Vector.<Component>();

    var length : int = _components.length;

    for (var i : int = 0; i < length; ++i)
        components.push(_components[i].clone()); // copy my local components to the new entity

    return new Entity(_name, _type, components);
}
```

The problem is, every time I create (design) a new component, I have to write (design) a clone() method inside of it AND keep track of all the parameters that were called on the constructor to create a brand new, default stated component.

So I end up with junk like this:

```
public class ComponentX
{
    protected var _defaultName : String;
    protected var _defaultStartingAnimation : String;
    protected var _defaultBroadcastAnimationEnded : Boolean;
    protected var _defaultOffsetX : Number;
    protected var _defaultOffsetY : Number;

    // other stuff hidden

    public function ComponentX(name : String, startingAnimation : String, broadcastAnimationEnded : Boolean = false, offsetX : Number = 0, offsetY : Number = 0) : void
    {
        super();

        _defaultName = name;
        _defaultStartingAnimation = startingAnimation;
        _defaultBroadcastAnimationEnded = broadcastAnimationEnded;
        _defaultOffsetX = offsetX;
        _defaultOffsetY = offsetY;
    }

    public function clone() : Component
    {
        return new ComponentX(_defaultName, _defaultStartingAnimation, _defaultBroadcastAnimationEnded, _defaultOffsetX, _defaultOffsetY);
    }

    // other methods
}
```

I really don't like this -- it's wasteful and error prone.

How could I best store the parameters of the EntityTemplateManager.register() function (including the components' constructors parameters) and use that new storage to create entities from instead?

I've tried some generic clone() methods like with a ByteArray or describeType(), but they don't work with protected / private variables.

Ideas?

Comment: why don't you just call create("zombie") everytime you need one? A lot easier and no cloning needed.

Comment: When I call create("zombie"), that's where it goes through and does the cloning.  I store one, un-used entity as a template for all the others to clone themselves from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few months ago I wrote my own Entity-Component manager too. I've done something like this (in your case):

```
EntityTemplateManager.register("zombie", [
    {type: PhysicsComponent, attr: {speed: 10}},
    {type: SpriteComponent, attr: {graphic: "zombie"}},
    {type: HealthComponent, attr: {health: 100}}
]);
```

Registering a new template works as below:

```
private static var definitions:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

public static function register(templateName:String, componentDefinitions:Array):void
{
    definitions[templateName] = componentDefinitions;
}
```

The `create` function retrieves the specified component template and create components like this:

```
var components:Vector.<Component> = new Vector.<Component>();

// Create all components
for each (var definition:Object in componentDefinitions) {
    var componentClass:Class = definition.type;
    var component:Component = new componentClass();

    // Set default parameters
    for (var prop:String in definition.attr) {
        component[prop] = definition.attr[prop];
    }

    components.push(component);
}

// Then create the entity and attach the freshly created components.
// ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  This looks perfect.  Thanks!